# sql query to count when question_id is same and user_id is different

Tags: php, sql

I have following table:

```
 res_id  quiz_id     sender_id   user_id     question_id   points
  1         1           2      33       20      0
  2         1           2      34       20      0   
  3         1           2      24       20      0
  4         2           3      22       2       1
  5         3           4      3        6       1
```

I want to get result if quiz_id is same for three rows and question_id is same and sender_id is same make sure user_id is different and points are 0. If this condition is satisfied pass value of 1 to the php variable here is example:

```
res_id  quiz_id     sender_id   user_id     question_id   points
  1         1           2      33       20      0
  2         1           2      34       20      0   
  3         1           2      24       20      0
```

Comment: I am assuming this data is from the database?  Do you have any PHP code to go along with this question?

Comment: Edit your question to show whatever PHP you currently have that is not working.

Comment: @afuzzyllama- php code is nothing but a variable like var $a=" sql statement "; I want to get the count for all the possible combinations above mentioned in this varable a. Thanks for looking.

Comment: what happens when you have multiple quiz_ids and matching sender_ids,user_id ect (more then 1 result set) how would you expect to handle them. Unless you use a `WHERE` somewhere in the query there is no uniqueness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "If this condition is satisfied pass value of 1 to the php variable" isn't quite clear to me (do you just want to know is there three (or more) rows which satisfy your query?) but the query should be something like

```
SELECT 
  count(*)
FROM tab t1
  JOIN tab t2 ON(t1.quiz_id = t2.quiz_id)AND(t1.question_id = t2.question_id)AND(t1.sender_id = t2.sender_id)
  JOIN tab t3 ON(t1.quiz_id = t3.quiz_id)AND(t1.question_id = t3.question_id)AND(t1.sender_id = t3.sender_id)
WHERE(t1.user_id <> t2.user_id)AND(t2.user_id <> t3.user_id)AND(t1.user_id <> t3.user_id)
      AND(t1.points = 0)AND(t2.points = 0)AND(t3.points = 0)
GROUP BY t1.quiz_id, t1.sender_id, t1.question_id
```

Comment: basically i want to get count of number of queries like this that are available in database. So if there are 10 querries which match above condition i want the variable $a to have value of 10. Thanks for the query i will try it now.

Comment: @ken See updated answer - I updated the query to include the COUNT / GROUP BY

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i think Lawrence is correct. I am getting resultset of 6 6 6 6 something like that. Not a single value. So i will have to figure out some other way to query this.

Comment: @ken What DB engine do you use? Try does using `count(1)` or `count(distinct t1.quiz_id)` make any difference.